# Как через bat скрипт добавить задачу в scheduler на запуск браузера до момента логирования?

Tags: windows, администрирование, bat

Написал bat который должен добавить задачу запускать браузер до момента логина пароля. Все компьютеры в одной сети где будет проводится данная настройка.

Суть в том что браузер автоматически запускался в режиме киоска каждый раз при старте windows. И если юзер захочет выйти(закрыть программу), только после этого появлялась возможность ввода логина пароля, это нужно для того чтоб те пользователи у которых нет логина пароля не могли выйдя из приложения, зайти и что-то делать в системе.

bat выбрал потому, что он позволяет автоматизировать процесс настройки. (Не нужно руками в планировщик вбивать все настройки)

Но проблема в том что скрипт добавляет задачу только, в случае если добавить расписание.

Пример скрипта:

```
@echo off
schtasks /create /sc ONSTART /tn "cwp" /tr "C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

А нужно, чтоб скрипт добавил задачу в scheduler, которая должна выполнятся 
именно до логирования.

Возможно в скрипте что-то не учел, или проблему можно решить в другой плоскости?

Comment: до "логирование" чего? Может имеется ввиду "до логина пользователя"?

Comment: так может и будете использовать режим киоска по его прямому назначению? http://remontka.pro/kiosk-mode-windows-10/

Comment: Любая программа, запускаемая до входа в систему, работает под суперпользователем *SYSTEM*, который даже более могущественный, чем встроенных администратор. И вы хотите запустить под ней обозреватель — одн из самых небезопасных программ.

Comment: @Arhad, в обозревателе будет отрыт сайт который лежит локально без доступа в сеть.

Comment: @KoVadim, также нужно запускать и на windows 7

Comment: @Dementiy1999 - режим киоска был даже в 98 винде. Скорее всего, в 7 все также, как и в 10.

Comment: А что вы будете делать если юзер у которого нет пароля закроет браузер?

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, если закроет ничего страшного. Для меня важны лишь те моменты о которых я написал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы запустить программу до входа в систему надо подменить winlogon (на свой страх и риск) или написать расширение через механизм GINA (перестал работать в Vista). По всей видимости, в таком виде задача нормального решения не имеет.

---

Но, как мне кажется, на самом деле вам надо просто запустить браузер. Это можно сделать и после входа в систему - если настроить автоматический вход в систему.

Вот полный план:

1. создать ограниченного пользователя для запуска браузера от его имени;
2. настроить для этого пользователя запуск браузера в режиме киоска;
3. настроить автоматический выход из системы при закрытии браузера;
4. настроить автоматический вход в систему от имени ограниченного пользователя.

Пункты 1 и 4 делаются через стандартными средствами, через панель управления.

Если пункт 3 вам на самом деле не важен (закрытия браузера не предусмотрено) - то в пункте 2 достаточно прописать запуск браузера в `HKU\(sid пользователя)\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\@shell` (ну, и настроить браузер).

Если пункт 3 важен - вам понадобится отдельная программа которая будет запускать браузер и ждать когда он закончит работу чтобы выйти из системы.